# How can I get my Hyper-V virtual machines to recognize my web camera?

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v, windows-11, camera

My host machine is running Windows 11 Home. I installed and used Hyper-V to standup a virtual machine (running Windows 11 Pro). I am attempting to get it so that I can use my web camera in my Hyper-V virtual machine, but the camera is not listed under the local devices and resources.

If I use Remote Desktop Connection, the web camera is listed under the local devices and resources, so I'm not sure what to do here. See images below for reference.

---

[image: Hyper-V Settings]

[image: Remote Desktop Connection Settings]

Comment: How exactly did you use Hyper-V on Windows 10 Home? That shouldn’t have been possible. Hyper-V cannot be enabled, or it’s not supposed to be possible, since that’s not a feature of Windows 10 Home. Have you tried just enabling the applicable checkbox?

Comment: @Ramhound: I have Windows 11 Home, and it is possible to run Hyper-V on that OS after installing the Hyper-V packages from Microsoft.

Comment: [Hyper-v isn’t a feature of Windows 11 Home.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v) Anyways, have you enabled, You have enabled Enhanced Session Mode?

Comment: @Ramhound: Yes, enhanced mode is enabled.